# Dia-Compe Gran Compe shot lever - is there a fix for 31.8mm bars?

Tags: fixed-gear, single-speed, brake-levers

I have a Dia-Compe [Gran Compe shot lever](http://www.diacompe.com.tw/product/gran-compe-shot-lever/) and want to change the bars on my track bike for 31.8 diameter bars — is there a fix (i.e. replacement clamp band) that anyone can point me to that I can use to change it from 25.4 to 31.8 diameter.  Dia-Compe does not seem to make an oversized version. Would be a shame not to use it.  Grateful for any advice/hacks.

Comment: Framing question - is there anything forcing you away from the original bars?   May have to just stay on the 25.4mm size for now.

Answer (score 2):

31.8 is the stem clamp diameter, this is known as oversized. The number that you are concerned with is usually 25.4 or 22.2. Further complicating this is that levers that mount almost up against the stem are sometimes 31.8 as in the case of cross bike interceptor levers. This size is common on cyclocross bikes, much less so elsewhere. You might look at the BMX product: "Gold Finger" that is available in 31.8. Cross levers will be much more affordable but are more delicate.